# Restrict Datasource Templates

Tags: sitecore, datasource, sitecore8.2

I'm trying to restrict the items shown in my multi-list.  I've looked at articles like this:  http://zacharykniebel.com/blog/sitecore/2014/june/26/constraining-the-sitecore-7-multilist-and-treelist-fields-with-and-without-search

I've tried implementing

```
DataSource=/sitecore/content/data/country sites&ExcludeTemplatesForDisplay=Country Site
```

But I'm still seeing both template types in my Multi-List.

Any suggestions of what else to try, I'm using Sitecore 8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those parameters only work for Treelist fields not multilist fields. Change it to a Treelist or TreelistEx and it should work.